# how to write a batch file so that each execution will make a folder and put the result into it

Tags: batch-file

Sorry if my title didn't make much sense.

So I current have a simple batch script as follows:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.pdf) do java -jar pdfbox-app-1.7.1.jar PDFToImage %%i
```

which basically converts .pdf files into .jpg files using a jar file.

But how do I make it so that it would make folder for each different jpg file and then put the jpg file into that folder?? Any idea?!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know how to create a folder? You can execute multiple commands in your DO clause if you open parenthesis after DO and then put one command per line, and then close parenthesis. You should be able to figure this out.

Comment: One other hint - `%%~ni` gives the base name of the file, without .pdf extension.

Comment: Thanks alot!!!! I figured it out last night haha xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For statements can work with blocks of commands.

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.pdf) do (
    java -jar pdfbox-app-1.7.1.jar PDFToImage ../%%i
    mkdir %%~ni
    move %%~ni.jpg %%~ni\
)
```